# How do i extract the standard error from a gaussian GLM model?

Tags: r, glm, standard-error

I wish to extract the standard error from my Gaussian GLM and my poisson GLM if anyone knows how i can do this?

code for simulated data and both models are below;

```
#data simulated before fitting models
set.seed(20220520)  
#simulating 200 values between 0 and 1 from a uniform distribution
x = runif(200, min = 0, max = 1) 

lam = exp(0.3+5*x)

y = rpois(200, lambda = lam) 

#before we do this each Yi may contain zeros so we need to add a small constant
y <- y + .1 
#combining x and y into a dataframe so we can plot
df = data.frame(x, y)

#Gausian GLM
model1 <- glm(y ~ x, 
          data = df,
          family = gaussian(link = 'log'))


#Poisson GLM
model2 <- glm(y ~ x, 
          data = df,
          family = poisson(link='log'))
```

Comment: What's wrong with `summary(model2)$coefficients[, 'Std. Error']`?

Comment: By "standard error" do you mean the standard error of the coefficients, or the residual standard deviation, or the standard error of predictions, or ... ?  (The Poisson GLM doesn't have a residual standard deviation in the same sense as the linear model does - you might want to give a little more context)

Comment: PS you should be fine with zeros in your data, you don't need to adjust them (a log-link Gaussian GLM is not the same as running a linear model on log-transformed data ...)

Comment: @BenBolker yep good point, here the standard error of the residuals is what i am looking for. Thanks for the advice on 0s too, i would just require this for my poisson model if i understand correctly?

Comment: You don't need to adjust the zeros for either the Poisson or the log-link Gaussian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a little deeper than might otherwise appear. In general, `sigma()` will extract the residual standard deviation:

> Extract the estimated standard deviation of the errors, the
> “residual standard deviation” (misnamed also “residual standard
> error”, e.g., in ‘summary.lm()’'s output, from a fitted model).

> Many classical statistical models have a *scale parameter*,
> typically the standard deviation of a zero-mean normal (or
> Gaussian) random variable which is denoted as sigma.  ‘sigma(.)’
> extracts the *estimated* parameter from a fitted model, i.e.,
> sigma^.

This works as expected for a linear model (`sigma(model1)`). **However**, it doesn't necessarily do what you're expecting for the Poisson model; it returns the square root of the *deviance* divided by the number of observations, which is analogous to the residual standard deviation but not the same.

```r
identical(
   sigma(model1),   ## 5.424689
   sqrt(sum(residuals(model1)^2)/(df.residual(model1)))
)  ## TRUE
```

```r
sigma(model2)  ## 1.017891
sqrt(sum(residuals(model2, type="response")^2)/(df.residual(model2)))  ## 5.452
```

(If you redo this calculation with `type = "deviance"` [the default value for `residuals.glm`], you *will* get the same value as `sigma()` ...)

If you want to compare goodness of fit, you should consider a metric like the AIC ...

PS you probably shouldn't add 0.1 to your response; not only is this unnecessary (either for a log-link Gaussian or for a Poisson model), it leads to a series of warnings about "non-integer x" when you fit the Poisson model (harmless in this case, but a further indication that you probably shouldn't do this); however, you **do** need to specify starting values for the log-link Gaussian model (`start = c(1,1)` seems to work).